# Finding a sequence of linear functionals on $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ of norm 1 and converging to zero pointwise

Tags: functional-analysis

I am totally stuck at the following problem...

I need to find a sequence of linear functionals on $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ of norm 1 and converging to zero pointwise. That is, $\{f_n\}$ in the dual of $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ such that each $f_n$ is of norm 1 and $f_n(x)$ goes to zero for each element $x$ of $L^{\infty}[0,1]$.

I tried everything I can think of. I tried to find $f_n$ in terms of integral w.r.t $L^1$ functions, tried to define them on the continuous functions and extend to $L^{\infty}[0,1]$. However nothing works....And it is so extremely frustrating.... Is there some magic way to solve this problem? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Since $L^1 \subset (L^{\infty})^*$, you can just find a sequence of $L^1$ functions with norm $1$ that converge pointwise to zero...

Comment: No, the pointwise convergence of $L^1$ function does not guarantee the pointwise convergence of the correspoonding linear functional on $L^{\infty}[0,1]$....That is why I am stuck

Comment: please...no help?.............

Comment: Right... I didn’t think of that. Actually, thinking about it, and comparing with the $\ell$ situation, it is even possible that weak-* convergence in $(L^{\infty})^*$ for $L^1$ functions implies convergence in $L^1$...

Comment: Oh it is the Fourier coefficients.....I now see that

Comment: Well, that is a quite nice example.